# Both belowskip and aboveskip not working

Tags: captions

I've tried everything I can, but can't seem to get the belowskip or aboveskip to work:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[textwidth=15cm,textheight=24cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{array, booktabs}
\usepackage[x11names,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{chemstyle}
\usepackage{chemnum}
\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\graphicspath{ {./Figures/} }
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\counterwithin{figure}{subsection}
\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[super]{nth}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{breakcites}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\usepackage{achemso}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{font=footnotesize,belowskip=0pt,aboveskip=0pt}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{nameref}
\usepackage[hyphens]{url}
\urlstyle{same}
\usepackage{glossaries}

\setlength\intextsep{0pt}

\title{TestX}
\author{elifnathan }
\date{May 2019}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\replacecmpd{taxol}
\includegraphics[scale=0.4]{example-image}
\caption{Taxol (\refcmpd{taxol}), with Conventional Ring Labelling and Atom Numbering Shown}
\label{first:chem:figure}
\end{figure}
\section{Section2}

\end{document}
```

[image: My Output]

Please help if you can! I need to remove some of the whitespace in my document.

Thanks!

Comment: we can not run your example to debug the issue as we don't have the image, can you reproduce the problem using `example-image` which is generally available for tests?  Your code shows `\begin{figure}` with no optional `[ht]` argument so it wouldn't normally be allowed mid page, but your image shows it under the section  header?

Comment: I've reproduced as requested - but yeah, there's no [ht], but this doesn't seem to be an issue? Adding it doesn't change anything.

Comment: unrelated but that is a very strange set of packages, why specify lmodern then change to mathptmx for example?

Comment: Because I'm not great at using LaTeX (first time) and am just trying to get everything functional.

Comment: the float placemet is changed to h because of the  chemstyle package (which seems odd, but that's what it does) not really sure which space you want to remove, there is almost none in the example, the space above the `\section` ? but it isn't that big?

Comment: @EliNathan My impression is that for someone who is using LaTeX for the first time, you are using *way* too many packages. You shouldn't copy `\usepackage` lines without knowing exactly what you need them for. The more `\usepackage` lines you have, the more things are difficult to predict (a bit like someone taking 20 different drugs at the same time...).

Comment: Thanks for the help guys - but none of these are working, when I use the \belowskip package, nothing works at all.

Comment: Also - in future please try to actually help me solve the problem I asked for, rather than giving me random feedback that isn't directly useful.

Answer (score 1):

The only space that could really be saved is around the title and section headings, you could use `titlesec` or simply use a class with less flamboyant headings, so with `article` you get

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[textwidth=15cm,textheight=24cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{chemstyle}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\usepackage{caption}\captionsetup{font=footnotesize,belowskip=0pt,aboveskip=0pt}
\usepackage{setspace}

\setlength\intextsep{0pt}

\title{TestX}
\author{elifnathan }
\date{May 2019}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}

\begin{figure}
\centering

\includegraphics[scale=0.4]{example-image}
\caption{Taxol , with Conventional Ring Labelling and Atom Numbering Shown}
\label{first:chem:figure}
\end{figure}
\section{Section2}

\end{document}
```

changing the first line to

```
\documentclass[12pt]{amsart}
```

you get

[image]

Comment: I can't change the formatting this way - my department won't allow it. 

The main issue is that the big gap between image and text occurs even if there is no heading, even if it is just a figure between two paragraphs.

Comment: @Eli There is no gap in the example you posted other than the space specified above the heading. Perhaps you could edit the question to change the example